# Animated TextField in Flutter: Swipe-up to Expand Not Working When Scrolling Is Enabled

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, swipe-gesture

i have created a TextField in Flutter that behaves similar to the Slack text field:

1. The TextField animates to full screen when swiped up and minimizes when swiped down.
2. In its minimized state, the TextField dynamically adjusts its height based on the content, up to 5 lines. After 5 lines, it enables
   scrolling.

I'm using an AnimatedContainer to handle the animation. Everything works fine except when the content crosses 5 lines and the TextField starts scrolling. At this point, the swipe-up action to expand the TextField to full screen stops working.

this is my code for the function:

```
       KeyboardVisibilityBuilder _getTextFieldContainer(BuildContext context) {
    return KeyboardVisibilityBuilder(
      builder: (context, isKeyboardVisible) {
        return Stack(
            children: [
              SingleChildScrollView(
               child: Container(
                   width: double.infinity,
                   decoration: BoxDecoration(
                     border:
                     Border.all(color: Get.isDarkMode ? darkGrey : lightGrey),
                     color: widget.backgroundColor,
                     borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                         topLeft: Radius.circular(8), topRight: Radius.circular(8)),
                   ),
                   child: Column(
                     mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                     children: [
                       Padding(
                           padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 12),
                           child: GestureDetector(
                               onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
                                 if (details.delta.dy > 0) { // Swipe down
                                   if (isFullScreen) {
                                     toggleFullScreen(context);
                                   }
                                 }
                                 else if (details.delta.dy < 0) { // Swipe up
                                   if (!isFullScreen) {
                                     toggleFullScreen(context);
                                   }
                                 }
                                 },
                               child: AnimatedContainer(
                                   duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                   curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                                   height: isFullScreen
                                       ? textFieldHeight
                                       : null, // Set height to null when not in full screen
                                   constraints: isFullScreen
                                       ? null
                                       : BoxConstraints(
                                       minHeight: bottomBarHeight,
                                       maxHeight: 5 * bottomBarHeight), // Set constraints for dynamic height
                                   child: IntrinsicHeight(
                                     child: TextField(
                                       focusNode: _textFieldFocusNode,
                                       controller: _chatController.textEditingController.value,
                                       minLines: 1,
                                       maxLines: isFullScreen ? null : (isKeyboardVisible ? 5 : 1),
                                       keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                                       textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
                                       autocorrect: false,
                                       cursorColor:
                                           Get.isDarkMode ? Colors.white : primaryColor,
                                       decoration: InputDecoration(
                                         enabledBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
                                           borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent),
                                         ),
                                         focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                                         hintText: widget.submitType == SubmitType.view
                                             ? 'Have a question? Ask now!'
                                             : 'Type here',
                                         suffixIcon: isKeyboardVisible || isFullScreen
                                             ? null
                                             : Row(
                                           mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                           children: [
                                             Obx(() => _getSpeechToText()),
                                             Obx(() => _getTextFieldSuffix()),
                                           ],
                                         ),
                                       ),
                         // Note: UI wont get updated with value without this setState, textEditingController will get updated.
                         onChanged: (value) {
                           setState(
                             () {},
                           );
                         },
                       ),
                                   ))
                     )),
                   isKeyboardVisible
                       ? _textFieldBottomBar(context)
                       : const SizedBox.shrink(),
                 ],
               )),
        ) ,
              if (isKeyboardVisible || isFullScreen)
                Positioned(
                bottom: 0,
                left: 0,
                right: 0,
                child: _textFieldBottomBar(context),
              )]);
      },
    );
  }
         @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return _getTextFieldContainer(context);
      }
```

and this is for for swiping up and swiping down and setting the textFieldHeight for fullscreen:

```
  double textFieldHeight = 50.0;
  double bottomBarHeight = 50.0;
  bool isFullScreen = false;

  void toggleFullScreen(BuildContext context) {
    setState(() {
      isFullScreen = !isFullScreen;
      double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
      textFieldHeight = isFullScreen ? screenHeight - bottomBarHeight : 50.0;
    });
  }
```

How can I resolve this issue so when it is in scrolling mode the swipe up can work?

Comment: Any chance of an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) [shared in a dartpad](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/wiki/Sharing-Guide)?